# Efficient way to find all combinations in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

I am looking for a efficient way in R to derive possible combinations.
I have a data frame with 3 columns and on the basis first column contents I am calculating all the possible combinations.

```
df <- data.frame("H" = c("H1","H2","H3","H4"), "W1" = c(95, 0, 85 ,0) , "W2" = c(50, 85, 0,0))
df$H <- as.character.factor(df$H)

nH <- nrow(df)
nW <- 2

library(plyr)
library(gtools)

if(nW<=5){

# Find all possible combinations
mat1 <- matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = nH)

for(i in 1:nH){
# mat1 <- rbind.fill.matrix(mat1, combinations(nH,nH-(i-1),df$H))

mat1 <- rbind.fill.matrix(mat1, t(combn(df$H,nH-(i-1))))

}
df_comb <- data.frame(mat1)

}
View(df_comb)
```

**df_comb** gives correct output. Above code works good for small data sets but when the values for H column is more than 15 , R results into out of memory.

Looking for ways in which calculation of combinations in above scenario can be done efficiently in R till H1, H2 .... H49, H50.

## EDIT:

Tried a different Approach, Now after certain number of possible combinations (in below case - 32767), applied **random sampling** to generate combinations using ratio method.

```
nH <- 26
nW <- 2

if(nW<=5){

# Find all possible combinations ~~~~~ Random Sampling
ncomb <- 0
for(i in 1:nH){
ncomb <- ncomb + choose(nH, nH-(i-1))
}
nmax <- 10000 # Total number of combinations cannot exceed 10000
mat1 <- matrix( nrow = 0, ncol = nH)

for(i in 1:nH){  # For each Group 26C1 26C2 26C3 ..... 26C25 26C26
ncombi <- choose(nH, nH-(i-1)) #For i = 1 , 26C25
ncombComputed <- ceiling(nmax/ncomb*choose(nH, nH-(i-1))) 

if(ncomb <=  32767 ){ # This condition is independent of NMAX - For 15   
#Combinations
  print("sefirst")
  final <- mat1
  print(paste(nH," ",i))
  abc <- combinations(nH,nH-(i-1),df$herbicide)
  mat1 <- rbind.fill.matrix(mat1, combinations(nH,nH-(i-1),df$H))
} 

else {
  print(i)
  print("second")
  combi <- matrix( nrow = 0, ncol = nH-(i-1))

  #random sampling

  while(nrow(combi) < ncombComputed){
    
    combi<- rbind(combi,sort(sample(df$herbicide,nH-(i-1))))
    
    combi <- unique(combi)
  }
  mat1 <- rbind.fill.matrix(mat1, combi)
}
}

df_comb_New <- data.frame(mat1)

}
```

The above code gives the result but for 26 Entries its taking 36 seconds for 10000 Combinations.Now I am looking that is there a way **to optimize the while loop** so that execution becomes faster or any other way to achieve the same result in efficient manner.

Comment: You will have RAM limitations well below H=50 however efficient your code is. Assuming each H is unique (which your code implies), there are 1.3 * 10^14 combinations just for H=50 of length 25. If each element of those were stored as 1 byte, each row of the matrix would require 25 bytes, so you'd be looking at 3 petabytes of memory for that set of combinations alone.

Comment: and you can calculate the number of combinations yourself using `choose`.

Comment: Might I ask what you will be doing with this matrix? Also, is a matrix really required, or can you live with a list?

Comment: @JosephWood Is list will  help here in optimization.... if yes, can try that. Matrix is used here as I need output in dataframe.

Comment: @MikeS Have tried a different approach to generate combinations using random sampling.Can that part be optimized further  or any other way to achieve the same result in efficient manner. Thank you.

Comment: @Roland Used Choose function and tried different approach, Can sampling part be optimized further or any other way to achieve the same result in efficient manner. Thank you.

Comment: The problem isn't just that you don't have enough memory to store all the combinations -- you probably don't have enough time to process them either.